# How to change navigation bar color in iOS 7 or 6?

Tags: ios, ios6, interface-builder, ios7

I want to change the color of the navigation bar color, but I'm not sure whether or not I should change the tint or the background. I know iOS 7 is going for a more flat design (even [recommending removing gradients](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/07/how-to-transition-app-designs-to-ios-7/)), but I am having trouble deciphering the two. Even if I set a background color, it doesn't do anything.

In this image, the background is set to green, but the bar is still blue:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7/18929980#18929980

Answer (score 107):

The behavior of tintColor for bars has changed on iOS 7.0. It no longer affects the bar's background and behaves as described for the tintColor property added to UIView.
To tint the bar's background, please use -barTintColor.

`navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor navigationColor];`

Comment: Confirmed, tintColor doesn't work in iOS 7 but barTintColor does.

Comment: You may also want to set navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO

Comment: Check the full answer in here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-to-change-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7

Answer (score 79):

If you want to have a solid color for your navigation bar in **iOS 6** similar to iOS 7 use this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

---

in **iOS 7** use the `barTintColor` like this:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

or

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: I am using a custom navigation bar and the above code was not working for me (ios7). I had to explicitly write this:
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

Comment: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; should work in iOS 7

Answer (score 36):

// In ios 7 :-

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

// In ios 6 :-

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks its working but how to change purticular viewcontroller navigation bar color please help me

Answer (score 11):

The background color property is ignored on a `UINavigationBar`, so if you want to adjust the look and feel you either have to use the `tintColor` or call some of the other methods listed under "Customizing the Bar Appearance" of the [UINavigationBar class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) (like `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:`).

Be aware that the `tintColor` property works differently in iOS 7, so if you want a consistent look between iOS 7 and prior version using a background image might be your best bet.  It's also worth mentioning that you can't configure the background image in the Storyboard, you'll have to create an `IBOutlet` to your `UINavigationBar` and change it in `viewDidLoad` or some other appropriate place.

Answer (score 5):

One more thing, if you want to change the navigation bg color in **UIPopover** you need to set `barStyle` to `UIBarStyleBlack`

```
if([UINavigationBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(barTintColor)]){ //iOS7
    navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to set it correctly for both iOS 6 and 7.

```
+ (void)fixNavBarColor:(UINavigationBar*)bar {
    if (iosVersion >= 7) {
        bar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        bar.translucent = NO;
    }else {
        bar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        bar.opaque = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking for iosVersion you should use respondsToSelector i.e. `[[UINavigationBar appearance] respondsToSelector:@selector(barTintColor)]`

Comment: For proxies you should use instancesRespondToSelector.  For this case it would be [UINavigationBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(barTintColor)]

Answer (score 4):

The complete code with version checking.

```
 if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

    // do stuff for iOS 7 and newer
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
}
else {

    // do stuff for older versions than iOS 7
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check iOS Version and simply set the tint color of Navigation bar.

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9529 green:0.4392 blue:0.3333 alpha:1.0];
}else{

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9529 green:0.4392 blue:0.3333 alpha:1.0];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on posted answered, this worked for me:

```
/* check for iOS 6 or 7 */
if ([[self navigationController].navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
    [[self navigationController].navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

} else {
    /* Set background and foreground */
    [[self navigationController].navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self navigationController].navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor blackColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    you can add bellow code in appdelegate.m .if your app is navigation based

    // for background color
   [nav.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    // for change navigation title and button color
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName,               
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontNAme" size:20],
    NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert the below code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() in AppDelegate.m

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor
    colorWithRed:26.0/255.0 green:184.0/255.0 blue:110.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using following code (in C#) to change the color of the NavigationBar:

```
NavigationController.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage (new UIImage (), UIBarMetrics.Default);
NavigationController.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage (new UIImage (), UIBarMetrics.LandscapePhone);
NavigationController.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
```

The trick is that you need to get rid of the default background image and then the color will appear.

Comment: Your code works for the navigationbar, but are you able to apply the same background to the status bar?

Comment: As far as I know in iOS6 you cannot change the status bar color. You only can make it "translucent". In iOS7 you can change the color of status bar but it is achieved through background image of NavigationBar. In iOS7 I'm using 1x1 pixel image with preferred color as NavigationBar background image and it is automatically extended also to the status bar (as described in Apple official iOS7 documentation).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change a color of a navigation bar, use `barTintColor` property of it. In addition, if you set any color to `tintColor` of it, that affects to the navigation bar's item  like a button.

FYI, you want to keep iOS 6 style bar, make a background image looks like previous style and set it.

For more detail, you can get more information from the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html

Answer (score 1):

In iOS7, if your navigation controller is contained in tab bar, splitview or some other container, then for globally changing navigationbar appearance use following method ::

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBarController class],nil] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` of your `ViewController.m`

`[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];`

this did work for me in iOS 6.. Try it..

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure about changing the tint vs the background color but this is how you change the tint color of the Navigation Bar:

Try this code..

`[navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor];`  //Red as an example.