# Change UINavigationBar Tint Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Hi I am trying to change the tint color of a newly created navigation bar but i am having difficulty getting the tint color to change and have tried various ways of implementing `tintColor`.  Here is how I am creating it.

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
    [navBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [settingsView addSubview:navBar];
```

Do I need to approach it differently or redraw it?

Comment: I get 248 results when I search SO for UINavigationBar and tint. Is it possible that you could derive some helpful information from at least one of those posts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change navigation bar color in iOS 7 or 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177010/how-to-change-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7-or-6)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this,

[navBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
[navBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 Has a method called `setBarTintColor` which works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Worked perfectly for me!

```
  [self.homeNavigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIcolor redcolor]];

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
UIColor *appcolor=[UIColor colorWithRed:63.0/255.0 green:148.0/255.0 blue:246.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor appcolor]];
```