# how to set navigation bar color on IOS 6/7

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, ios7, uinavigationbar

i am setting my `UINAvigatoinBar` color like so with hex color:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x212121);
```

it works well on `IOS7` but in lower versions it crash with the following :

```
[UINavigationBar setBarTintColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

how can i do it right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change navigation bar color in iOS 7 or 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177010/how-to-change-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7-or-6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the best way is to be using the respondToSelector method instead of checking the iOS version:

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:NAVBAR_BACKGROUNDCOLOR];
}
else {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:NAVBAR_BACKGROUNDCOLOR];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: Its good , but using appearance it will change the colour of navigation bar universally not for a particular view's navigation bar.

Answer (score 5):

the best solution is detect which version of os is:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

   NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
   int ver_int = [ver intValue];

   if (ver_int < 7) {
       [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor UIColorFromRGB(0x212121)]];
    }

   else {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor UIColorFromRGB(0x212121)];
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the OS version. If it is IOS7, then you can use **barTintColor**. In IOS6, you can use **tintColor**

```
if ([self checkOSVersion] >= 7) {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor UIColorFromRGB(0x212121)]];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    } else {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor UIColorFromRGB(0x212121)]];
    }
```

define the OS version checking method as

```
- (int)checkOSVersion {

    NSArray *ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    int osVerson = [[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    return osVerson;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(45/255.f) green:(45/255.f) blue:(45/255.f) alpha:1.0f];
```