# How to change UINavigationController navigationBar backgroundColor with default animation in specific viewController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar, navigationitem

How to change UINavigationController navigationBar backgroundColor with default animation in specific viewController.
Every question that i find in the web was without animation.

Similar question here [How to change the color of navigation bar on a specific view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807795/how-to-change-the-color-of-navigation-bar-on-a-specific-view) but this post answers only change the navigationBar background color without animation.

The video for linkedIn iOS Application which did this behavior.

- https://mohamadreza.codes/asset/navigationBarColor.MP4

Comment: UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.navigationBar.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                 }).

Comment: @FaheemRahman this method only change the color with animation, i wanted to know how to change the color with swipe transition amount, i think the answer is around UIViewPropertyAnimator and how much UINavigationController did swipe...